# Cant resolve setMapStyle() while creating custom styled map in android map v2

Tags: android, json, google-maps, styling

I was trying to achieve a custom color scheme in The map in my app. So i called a custom JSON (JSON was created with the tool provided by google) inside the onMapReady() function as per google instructed. my onMapready function is as given below

```
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
               try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Can't find style.", e);
        }
    }
```

But whatever I tried it shows error in the function setMapStyle().

[image: error]

I'm a beginner in android programming so if it's even kind of small obvious solution please do help.. I have searched a lot to get the sollution..

Thanks In advance

Comment: `GoogleMap` does not provide `setMapStyle(...)` method

Comment: then what about this article https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling

Comment: Update you google play service version in  build.gradle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @M D says, you need to update your `build.gradle` to use the last version of [Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). Current version is `9.6.1`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

After updating your `build.gradle` you will be able to style your map, but take into account that, as [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) says, styling works only on the normal map type.

Comment: thanks mate let me try it...right now the internet here is a bit slow ...so it takes a while to download...so i will update it if this does the job...thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

**Cannot resolve googleMap.setMapStyle() FIXED**

Update all **Google play service** library to **9.8.0** solve my problem

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```